# how to hide and show text if checkbox is checked vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

So far my code is like this and they only enable and disable the Textbox.

```
Private Sub CheckBox17_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox17.CheckedChanged

        If CheckBox17.Checked = True Then

        TextBox1.Enabled = False

    ElseIf CheckBox17.Checked = False Then

        TextBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I need some codes that hide the text when the checkbox is checked and show it when checked.

Comment: Your wishes are our commands. Although it might take us a while, sorry about this (hopefully this will not provoke you to decide stop requesting things from us). Someone in our team will start working on your problem ASAP. Thanks for choosing us.

Comment: Use `TextBox1.Enabled = Not CheckBox17.Checked`. It is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox is checked copy the textbox contents to a string variable and set the textbox text property to an empty string (consideder setting textbox enabled to false). If the check is checked assign the string variable to the textbox text property again.

Answer (score 1):

a cording to question i this this example help
this example show **How to Hide and Show the Password Using a CheckBox**

i create a new Windows Form Application. After that, do the Form just like this.

[image]

Double click the checkbox and do this following code in the method. This method will set the password into bullets to hide it, or set it into letters to know the password that you have input exactly according to your desire.

'CHECKING IF THE CHECKBOX WAS CHECKED OR NOT.

`If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then`
'IF TRUE, IT SHOW THE TEXT
`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
Else`

'IF FALSE, IT WILL HIDE THE TEXT AND IT WILL TURN IT INTIO BULLETS.

`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
End If`

Go back to the design views, double click the form and do this following code in the Form_Load.

'HIDE THE TEXT OF THE TXTPASS ON THE FIRST LOAD

`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = True`

***These are the full codes that you have made.***

`Public Class Form1
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged`

'CHECKING IF THE CHECKBOX WAS CHECKED OR NOT.

`If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then`

'IF TRUE, IT SHOWS THE TEXT

`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
Else`

'IF FALSE, IT WILL HIDE THE TEXT AND IT WILL TURN INTO BULLETS.

`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
End If
End Sub`

`Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`

'HIDE THE TEXT OF THE TXTPASS ON THE FIRST LOAD

`txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
End Sub
End Class`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want the textbox to be unseen should this box be checked.  Hope I'm reading that correctly.  So you would just use the visible property.

```
 Private Sub CheckBox17_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox17.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox17.Checked = True Then
        TextBox1.Visible = False
        TextBox1.Enabled = False

    ElseIf CheckBox17.Checked = False Then
        TextBox1.Visible = True
        TextBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the font color for the text to the same as the background color.. and its gone:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_DataReview" class="standardCheckbox" runat="server" Width="90%" **ForeColor="white"** TabIndex="115" />
```